# ShellScriptを実行したときに、ユーザーをrootにできません

Tags: bash, shellscript

**現象**
ShellScriptを実行したときに、ユーザーをrootになることができない。

**期待値**
ShellScriptを実行したときに、ユーザーをrootにしたい。

**再現手順**
下記のシェルスクリプトを実行しました。

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo sh -c "

if [ "whoami" = "root" ]; then
 echo OK
else
 echo NG
fi

apt update
apt upgrade

#以下省略
"
```

Comment: スクリプト中にある「echo NGfi」(「echo NG」と「fi」の間の改行の入れ忘れ)はコピペミスですか？実際のスクリプトもそうなっていますか？
動かないとしたらエラーメッセージ等は出ますか？

Comment: @hidezzz コピペミスでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スクリプト中のダブルクォート`"`の使い方がいろいろとおかしいと思います。

1. まず`sudo sh -c "`で始まるダブルクォート`"`とスクリプト中に含まれているダブルクォート`"`が重複していて構文的におかしくなっています。
2. また`sudo sh -c`で使用するクォートはその内部の展開が外側のシェルスクリプトの側で行われてしまうのを極力避けるためにシングルクォート`'`で囲むべきです。
3. `"whoami"`はその文字列そのものではなく、`whoami`コマンドの出力結果文字列を取得することを意図していると思われるので、ダブルクォート`"`ではなくバッククォート「`」で囲む必要があります。

とりあえず以上のことを加味した修正例が以下のようになります。

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo sh -c '

if [ `whoami` = "root" ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo NG
fi

    apt update
    apt upgrade

#以下省略
'
```

またそもそも、処理をわざわざ`sudo sh -c`で囲まない書き方にすればもっとすっきりと記述できるはずだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

とりあえず、「if」〜「fi」までを実験してみたところ、こんな問題がありました。

1. if文以下の「"」は「\」でエスケープしないと、そこで閉じ扱いになってしまう
2. 「whoami」は「`」で囲わないと、ただの「whoami」という文字列になってしまう
3. 「`」も「\」でエスケープしないと、スクリプト実行時点（sudo実行前）に展開されてしまう

これらを直してみたのが以下になりますので、試してみてください。

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo sh -c "
if [ \`whoami\` = \"root\" ]; then
  echo OK
else
  echo NG
fi
"
```